# Como Enviar informação de um site JavaScript para o servidor NODE.js

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, api

Galera, eu tenho um site em javascript onde pego informaçoes de uma API Rest (json)

eu gostaria de madnar essas informaçoes para meu servidor (Um node.js que eu criei que se conecta com o banco de dados)

é minha primeira vez trabalhando com desenvolvimento web , gostaria de saber como faço a conecçao entre os dois?

**Meu front end**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <style>     
            .bodyFrame {
                margin: 40px;
            }

            .headerLabel {
                font-weight: bold;
            }

        </style>

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="bodyFrame">
            <h2 style="text-align:center;">WIDS JSON Retrieval Example</h2>

            <button type="button" onclick="makeServiceCall()">Retrieve JSON Data</button>
            <br /><br />

            <label class="headerLabel">Programs</label>
            <ul id="programUL"></ul>
        <div>

        <script>

            function makeServiceCall() {                    
                var url = "http://widsservicedev.yaharasoftware.com/WidsService/JSON/GetPortagePrograms/?apikey=104043F0-9C24-4957-879D-046868973CC4&callback";

                $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
                    //var myArray = [];
                    //myArray[0] = data;
                    parseProgramData(data, url);
                });                 
            }

            function parseProgramData(jsonData, url) {      

                $("#dataHeader").empty();
                $("#dataHeader").append('<b>' + url + '</b>');

                var programUL = document.getElementById("programUL");       

                for (var pgmIndex = 0; pgmIndex < jsonData.Programs.length; pgmIndex++) {                   
                    var pgmLi = document.createElement("li");
                    var program = jsonData.Programs[pgmIndex];
                    var programInfoRevision = program.ProgramInfoRevisions[0];
                    var numberTitle = programInfoRevision.ProgramNumber + " " + programInfoRevision.ProgramTitle;
                    pgmLi.appendChild(document.createTextNode(numberTitle));
                    programUL.appendChild(pgmLi);                   

                    var linebreak = document.createElement("br");
                    pgmLi.appendChild(linebreak);

                    var poLabel = document.createElement("label");
                    poLabel.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Program Outcomes"));
                    poLabel.classList.add("headerLabel");                   
                    pgmLi.appendChild(poLabel);                 

                    var pgmOutcomeUL = document.createElement("UL");
                    pgmLi.appendChild(pgmOutcomeUL);

                    for (var poIndex = 0; poIndex < program.ProgramOutcomes.length; poIndex++) {                    
                        var poLi = document.createElement("li");
                        poLi.appendChild(document.createTextNode(program.ProgramOutcomes[poIndex].Description));
                        pgmOutcomeUL.appendChild(poLi);
                    }                   
                }

            }
        </script>


    </body>

    <footer>        
    </footer>
</html>
```

**Meu node.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/', function (req, res) {

    var sql = require("mssql");

    // config for your database
/*    var config = {
        user: 'papercut',
        password: 'Portage.2018',
        server: 'devsqlcl2:1433', 
        database: 'AgrM6',
        port: "1433",
        dialect:",ssql",
        dialectOptiond:"SQLEXPRESS"
    };*/

    // connect to your database
    sql.connect('mssql://xxx:xxxx@xxxx:1433/xxx', function (err) {

        if (err) console.log(err);

        // create Request object
        var request = new sql.Request();

        // query to the database and get the records
        request.query('select * from dbo.balance_papercut', function (err, recordset) {

            if (err) console.log(err)

            // send records as a response
            res.send(recordset);

        });
    });
});

var server = app.listen(5000, function () {
    console.log('Server is running..');
});
```

Obrigado.

Comment: Dica: Não poste dado de conexões verdadeiras nas perguntas, use sempre fakes.

Answer (score 1):

o verbo get apenas recupera dados do servidor, você quer fazer envio de dados no sentido oposto, você deve fazer um envio via POST.

No node você vai precisar do seguinte:

Instale o body-parser via npm
depois acrescente a seguinte configuração no seu server.js antes do app.get(...:

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json()); 
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

agora substitua o app.get por

```
app.post('/', function(req, res) {
    var body = req.body;


});
```

na variável body vc vai ter o json enviado do client

agora na parte do client vc precisa fazer um envio via Ajax POST como no exemplo abaixo:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success,
  dataType: dataType
});
```

Comment: uma duvida, esse body, recebe tudo que o meu cliente enviar?

outra coisa
url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success,
  dataType: dataType

aqui, o data, seria a informaçao que eu queira mandar? o url é o endereço do cliente?

Comment: Sim o body possui todos os dados enviados para o servidor, estes dados vão estar em formato json. Existem outros formatos... isso você informará pelo parâmetro datatype. Vai de json que é o melhor pro seu cenário.

Comment: data é o json propriamente dito e datatype se não me engano agora aqui de cabeça é o MIME type do json "application/json"

Comment: Ficaria algo assim?
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: (localhost/500 [ou o endereço do servidor?],
  data: [VARIAVEL COM AS INFORMAÇOES QUE QUERO],
  success: success,
  dataType: MIME
});

Comment: dataType: "application/json" , a Url é a do servidor que se estiver rodando local vai ser localhost mesmo...